# Make a view inside Views folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to have working `.cshtml` inside Views(not Views sub folders), like `_ViewImports`, but my own view. Or is it possible to redirect from `/Views` file to `/Views/Subfolder` view?

I found a solution. All you need is just to add MapRoute before existing one inside Startup.cs, like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                // Short link to a method
                routes.MapRoute(
                    "AnyName",
                    "NameOfYourIActionResult",
                    new {controller = "Controller_Name.cs", action = "IActionResult Method"}
                );

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to have a working `.cshtml` file inside Views folder. As for redirecting, no idea what you even mean. You can render the view by passing a path to the subfolder if that's what you mean...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean returning view form another location rather than default `/View` folder, yes it's possible.

You can explicitly specify the View that you want to use:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(@"~/Your/View/Location/Index.cshtml");
}
```

or by customizing view engine:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RazorViewEngine rve = new RazorViewEngine();
    rve.PartialViewLocationFormats =
        rve.ViewLocationFormats =
            rve.MasterLocationFormats =
                new string[] {
                   "~/Your/View/Location/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                   "~/Your/View/Location/Shared/{1}/{0}.cshtml"};
     rve.AreaMasterLocationFormats =
        rve.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats =
            rve.AreaViewLocationFormats =
                new string[] {
                   "~/Your/View/Location/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                   "~/Your/View/Location/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{1}/{0}.cshtml"};
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(rve);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have a working .cshtml directly in view folder and if u want to redirect why not modify RouteConfig.cs .

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```